# Should multiple simultaneous account suspensions result in suspensions across the entire network?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, account-suspension

There is a certain user who is suspended on this site and on the English site. They have also caused trouble and have a record of poor answers and vote counts on other sites. This person seems to have a need to cause trouble and can't behave themselves even though they've already been suspended on one site.

Although they have avoided trouble on the main SO site, a look at recent answers is not promising.

I propose that anyone who has been sufficiently misbehaving on 2 sites really needs a time out across the whole network. I know the suspensions are not coordinated currently, but I think this needs to be implemented.

Comment: I know there is this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60938/when-a-users-account-is-suspended-why-are-not-all-their-accounts-suspended What I am proposing is when there are multiple suspensions. It's not like they are misbehaving in a single location. It has progressed beyond that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know how much we're supposed to discuss, but some network mods were talking about this exact idea a few days ago, for the same reason. The general consensus seemed to be that people shouldn't get banned everywhere just for screwing up on a couple sites, but if they have a history then mods should feel free to skip the warnings/low day suspensions on new sites and go straight to banning them for multiple weeks when they do the same thing there. I've never seen a user banned on one site immediately move on to doing the same things on another site, so I'm not sure a network-wide ban is really all that effective

Comment: The length of [timed suspensions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) generally increases with repeated problems. If you've become aware of similar behavior by a user repeated across the network, I would be in favor as counting them all together as "repeat offenses" in determining the appropriate response.

Comment: isn't the point here to get some sort of ruling from SOIS? That's what I thought the reason for the question was... Also, I upvote @Robert's thought process +1 ;)

Comment: @drachenstern It looked like a feature request to add a "ban everywhere" button; I was explaining why that's probably not necessary

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha. ;)